# MySQL : 1 relational table with 3 colmuns OR 3 relational tables with 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in a mySql (innoDb) database : Clubs, Members, and Years.

**Which solution is better, and why ?**

**Solution 1 : 3 many-to-many tables (2 columns)**

- Clubs_Members (id club, id member)
- Members_Years (id member, id year)
- Years_Clubs (id year, id club)

**Solution 2 : 1 table for everything (3 columns)**

- Clubs_Members_Years (id club, id member, id year)

More specific informations :

- Clubs and Members database contain 5-8 columns
- Year only has 1 column
- There are not so much rows

Comment: Depends on what you try to model. If the year is an attribute of the membership, which seems plausible, solution 2 is the right one.

Comment: With solution 1, then what if one wants to get all members of a certain club in a certain year? My vote goes to Solution 2, or solution 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are not so many rows, it does not matter performance-wise.

The first solution is more efficient if the data will be queried in groups of 2 non-relational tables. However, queries for data in 3 non-relational tables will require a more complex query with INNER JOIN on all three relational tables.

The second solution retrieves more data, but makes queries more simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'll advise you not to use any of the solutions.
According to the information you've provided, I don't see any reason why **Years** should be a table of its own since it doesn't have many rows.

This is my solution
clubs_members (id club, id member, year)